# Inversify using container module to load shared dependencies

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I have a dependency diagram as such in my application. I want to use the `containerModule` api of [inversify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCKO9m.png) to load my dependencies.

[image]

The dependency is from `A -> B` and `C -> B`. However, inversify does not allow for 'duplicate bindings'.

Suppose module `D`(the top level module) depends on `Module A and C`, then I would try to build the dependency graph from the bottom up starting from `B -> (A + C) -> D`. However, If I load `containerModule B` from `containerModule A` and `containerModule C`, and proceed to load `containerModule A` and `containerModule C` in `containerModule D`, I would have ambiguous bindings when I try to resolve my dependencies in in `containerModule D` because I would have loaded `B` dependencies twice in `A and C`.

What would be a best practice for dealing with such a situation ? I believe it would be quite common in OO applications.

EDIT:
Currently I am defining a `containerModule` for `A, B, C and D`. This is so that I can easily unit test each module. I would like to reuse these `containerModules` for building the dependency graph. What I can think of now is to manually `unload` and `load` back `containerModules` that have been binded twice. For example, `in D`, I would call something like

```
container.load(containerModuleB, containerModuleA, containerModuleC)
container.unbind(containerModuleB)
container.bind(containerModuleB)
```